# Using GetMem for Allocation of Multidimensional arrays

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I to create `multidimensional(2D, 3D, 4D)` arrays using GetMem and `PointerMath`?

Comment: Well, it all depends. Ragged arrays? Or true multi-dimensional? If the former use  dynamic arrays. If the latter use a linear array and do the indexing.

Comment: What trouble are you having with the task? Please [edit] your question to demonstrate how much you understand, and which part you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is better without an extra variable.

```
var
  I, J: Integer;
  A: PInteger;
begin
  GetMem(A, 10 * 10 * SizeOf(Integer));

  for I := 0 to 10 - 1 do
  for J := 0 to 10 - 1 do
  PInteger(@A[I * 10])[J] := Random(10);


  for I := 0 to 10 - 1 do
  for J := 0 to 10 - 1 do
  WriteLn(I,',',J,':',PInteger(@A[I * 10])[J]);
```

Answer (score 4):

`GetMem()` only knows about 1-dimensional memory - you specify a byte count, it allocates that many bytes.  Period.  You would have to divide that memory up into sub-sections to handle them as multi-dimensional arrays, eg:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
var
  numCols, numRows, iRow, iCol: Integer;
  arr, pRow: PInteger; // an array of integers, for example
begin
  numCols := ...;
  numRows := ...;
  GetMem(arr, (numCols * numRows) * SizeOf(Integer));
  try
    for iRow := 0 to numRows-1 do
    begin
      pRow := @arr[iRow * numCols];
      for iCol := 0 to numCols-1 do
      begin
        // use pRow[iCol] as needed...
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(arr);
  end;
end;
```

To expand this to 3D, 4D, etc, simply multiply the initial allocation by the additional dimensions, and then index into the relevant sections as needed, eg:

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}    
var
  numX, numY, numZ, iX, iY, iZ: Integer;
  arr, pX, pY: PInteger;
begin
  numX := ...;
  numY := ...;
  numZ := ...;
  GetMem(arr, (numX * numY * numZ) * SizeOf(Integer));
  try
    for iY := 0 to numY-1 do
    begin
      pY := @arr[iY * (numX * numZ)];
      for iX := 0 to numX-1 do
      begin
        pX := @pY[iX * numZ];
        for iZ := 0 to numZ-1 do
        begin
          // use pX[iZ] as needed...
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(arr);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Is it possible to use double pointers here? I would like to have [][].

Comment: Not with a single memory block, since each dimension would have to point at the next dimension in order for `[]` dereferencing to work. In this case, you would need to allocate multiple arrays that point at each other. In which case, you are better off using dynamic arrays instead of `GetMem()`, eg: `var arr: array of array of Integer; SetLength(arr, numCols, numRows); // use arr[iCol, iRow] as needed...`

Comment: Hmm i better benchmark it. This is really easy with 1 malloc in C.

Comment: In both C and Delphi, each `[]` dereferences a pointer to access the value being pointed at. So to use multidimensional `[][]` indexing, you need a pointer to the next dimension in the array, for each dimension. Delphi and C are no different in this regard. So you cannot perform a single `GetMem()`/`malloc()` for multidimensional data and expect to use `[][]` indexing on that array directly, the required pointers are not present. You would have to use separate pointer variables (like my example above shows), or allocate arrays of pointers to point at other arrays, one array for each dimension.

Comment: Yea your approach is faster, and easier too.