# Create 2D array using getmem

Tags: arrays, delphi, delphi-7

How can I create a 2D array using `getmem`? I tried an approach similar to C but it seems this does not compile as expected.

```
var
  arr:PInteger;
begin
  getmem(arr, 5*5*sizeof(integer));
  arr[5];  //on this compiler produces error "Array type required"
end;
```

This is a homework assignment task that explicitly requires a solution using only `getmem`.

Comment: You talk about 2D arrays, but your attempted de-reference presents only a single index. There are quite a few ways to index into an array. Hard to know what's best with no detail provided. It looks like this is homework, but you haven't told us your task in detail. Have you asked your tutor?

Comment: @DevidHeffernan yes it is task in university.
I just need to create a 2D array and fill it using getmem. I tried to do like it was here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957977/using-getmem-for-allocation-of-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that you have a more detailed description of the task than we do?  What happens next is that we suggest something, and you say, "oh, my task doesn't allow me to do that".  That's no fun for us. Why don't you do your own homework? Did you not go to class where you were told how to do this? What do your text books say? Why did you think that you could treat a pointer as an array? Was that taught in class? Did you ask your tutor?

Comment: I tried to do it myself. I tried to do it as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957977/using-getmem-for-allocation-of-multidimensional-arrays with 2D arrays and it doesn't work.
All my task is just to create a 2D array using getmem. And nothing more. No, that wasn't taught in class (for Russia it's normal to give task and only after some months explain how it works).
I thought that i could treat pointer as array because that was done here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957977/using-getmem-for-allocation-of-multidimensional-arrays

Comment: No, it would not work because Delphi 7 doesn't support `$POINTERMATH ON`. Did you skip the class where you were taught how to do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't skip classes. It just wasn't explained. It's normal for Russian universities to give task and only after month or so explain how it works.

Comment: OK, well that sounds odd to me! Without `$POINTERMATH ON` you'll have to declare an array type. `type TIntegerArray = [0..0] of Integer; PIntegerArray = ^TIntegerArray;` Then you can declare `arr` to be of type `PIntegerArray` and use `arr^[i]` to index. You'll need to disable range checking too to avoid runtime range check errors. Or use a very large upper bound for your array type. All in all, it's pretty lame, but if that's the task you've been set .......

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks! That's what i need. After working with java and c++ it was hard for me to understand pascal's logic of arrays.

Comment: Are you sure the requirement is to use GetMem rather than use dynamic arrays?

Comment: @Remko Yes, requirement is to use getMem.

Answer (score 1):

As David noted in comments, without `POINTERMATH` support, you can really only do something like this.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
type
  TIntArray = array [0..0] of integer;
  PIntArray = ^TIntArray;

var
  p : PIntArray;
  i : integer;
begin
  GetMem(p, 5*5*SizeOf(integer));
  for i := 0 to 24 do p^[i] := i;
  for i := 0 to 24 do
    WriteLn(Format('i=%d, value = %d', [i,p^[i]]));
  ReadLn;
  FreeMem(p);
end.
```

The question is about a 2D array, however, so we can presume you want 2D indexing behaviour.  You might think that you could extend the above as so :

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
type
  T2DIntArray = array [0..0, 0..0] of integer;
  P2DIntArray = ^T2DIntArray;

var
  p2d : P2DIntArray;
  i, j : integer;
begin
  GetMem(p2d, 5*5*SizeOf(integer));
  for i := 0 to 4 do
    for j := 0 to 4 do p2d^[i,j] := i*j;
  for i := 0 to 4 do
    for j := 0 to 4 do
      WriteLn(Format('i=%d, j=%d, value = %d', [i,j,p2d^[i,j]]));
  ReadLn;
  FreeMem(p2d);
end.
```

But this produces nonsensical results.  From the compiled assembly, it's pretty easy to see what's going on :

```
Project1.dpr.16: for i := 0 to 4 do
0041A522 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041A524 A3CC1E4200       mov [$00421ecc],eax
Project1.dpr.17: for j := 0 to 4 do p2d^[i,j] := i*j;
0041A529 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041A52B A3D01E4200       mov [$00421ed0],eax
0041A530 A1CC1E4200       mov eax,[$00421ecc]       //  load i into EAX
0041A535 F72DD01E4200     imul dword ptr [$00421ed0]//  EAX = i*j
0041A53B 8B15C81E4200     mov edx,[$00421ec8]       //  load p2d into EDX 
0041A541 8B0DCC1E4200     mov ecx,[$00421ecc]       //  load i into ECX
0041A547 8D148A           lea edx,[edx+ecx*4]       //  offset p2d by i*SizeOf(integer) 
0041A54A 8B0DD01E4200     mov ecx,[$00421ed0]       //  load j into ECX
0041A550 89048A           mov [edx+ecx*4],eax       //  move i*j to EDX + j*sizeOf(integer)
0041A553 FF05D01E4200     inc dword ptr [$00421ed0]
0041A559 833DD01E420005   cmp dword ptr [$00421ed0],$05
0041A560 75CE             jnz $0041a530
0041A562 FF05CC1E4200     inc dword ptr [$00421ecc]
```

So clearly this isn't working - the compiler expects the first dimension to have unit size so you end up indexing

> 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,
>   1, 2, 3, 4, 5,
>   2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
>   ...etc

if you change the definition to

```
type
  T2DIntArray = array [0..4, 0..4] of integer;
  P2DIntArray = ^T2DIntArray;
```

then everything works as expected.

```
Project1.dpr.16: for i := 0 to 4 do
0041A522 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041A524 A3CC1E4200       mov [$00421ecc],eax
Project1.dpr.17: for j := 0 to 4 do p2d^[i,j] := i*j;
0041A529 33C0             xor eax,eax
0041A52B A3D01E4200       mov [$00421ed0],eax
0041A530 A1CC1E4200       mov eax,[$00421ecc]
0041A535 8D0480           lea eax,[eax+eax*4]  // this is more like it
0041A538 8B15C81E4200     mov edx,[$00421ec8]
0041A53E 8D0482           lea eax,[edx+eax*4]  // and this..
0041A541 8B15D01E4200     mov edx,[$00421ed0]
0041A547 8B0DCC1E4200     mov ecx,[$00421ecc]
0041A54D 0FAF0DD01E4200   imul ecx,[$00421ed0]
0041A554 890C90           mov [eax+edx*4],ecx  // so we get what we want
0041A557 FF05D01E4200     inc dword ptr [$00421ed0]
0041A55D 833DD01E420005   cmp dword ptr [$00421ed0],$05
0041A564 75CA             jnz $0041a530
0041A566 FF05CC1E4200     inc dword ptr [$00421ecc]
```

But, naturally, this is not terribly flexible.  You have to define a fixed bound for the type at compile time, which isn't very satisfying. The compiler needs a type definition with well defined dimension sizes to be able to correctly calculate the index at runtime.  Multidimensional behaviour therefore has to be implemented manually (using a linear index conversion) in any general case.

None of this is a sensible way to do things in Delphi.  I understand this is a school assignment, but it feels a bit like a C programmer teaching a Delphi course.  If you want to do this sort of thing in this sort of way, Delphi isn't really the right fit, I don't think.  In newer versions of Delphi you have more flexibility (with `POINTERMATH`), but even then the use case for this style of programming has to be considered extremely limited.

Comment: For the 2D array, you have to convert from two indices to linear index at runtime, `LinearIndex := iRow*nCol + iCol` kind of code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That's an alternative, yes, but it doesn't produce true 2D indexing behaviour.  The question was asking about a 2D array - I take that to mean they want to index like `p^[i,j]`.

Comment: That's not possible unless the size of all but the outermost dimensions are known at compile time, which means that manual indexing is needed. Not many languages support multidimensional arrays with size only known at runtime. Fortran is the prime example.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed. I was beating around the bush a bit since this was an academic question.  I've updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: Actually, doing this with pointers and `GetMem`, in Delphi, is pretty backward and unnecessary. Everyone who knows Delphi a little would use dynamic arrays. So indeed, one gets the impression that the teacher does not know Delphi very well.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis For perf one might choose to use a multidimensional array rather than a ragged array, but I doubt that's really the issue here

Comment: @David: If speed is an issue and the dimensions are **not** known at compile time, I would use a monodimensional dynarray of `m * n` elements and access it at index `[x * n + y]`. If needed very often, and in a recent Delphi, I would probably implement this as a record with methods and properties.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis That's a multidimensional array but the compiler cannot do the indexing for you.

Comment: Whether an array is multidimensional or monodimensional is generally a matter of interpretation (and indexing) anyway.

Comment: This task is from university. And yes, task is strange, because there are dynamic arrays and more efficient ways of memory management.

Comment: @Rudy It's always a matter of interpretation. A multidimensional array is a contiguous block of memory so can be thought of as one dimensional. They important distinction is with jagged arrays.